# Going to a link in the same rails application through a controller's action does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httprequest, httpresponse

I want the result of a web service (located in the same app) in my view, so I am fetching it in action like:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @cuisines = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/v1/cuisines')
  end
end
```

On hitting this action as: `http://localhost:3000/merchants/list`, it takes too long to load and eventually gives the `Net::ReadTimeout` exception.

I have the same app deployed to heroku so when I point to that instance, it works fine:

```
class MerchantsController < ApplicationController
  def list
    @cuisines = HTTParty.get('http://bogoapi.herokuapp.com/v1/cuisines')
  end
end
```

Is there a solution to it? If no, what makes it to behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

WEBrick - Rails default , build-in server, is a single-thread server. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WEBrick). 
 You make one call and make another call inside the logic of the first request. Your second request will never be executed until the first one is finished.

I suppose, the heroku instance will work ok - it is multi-thread. But I would propose changing your code instead. You can turn your separate service into a rails engine, for example.

Comment: Firstly, I am using rails 5 so no Webrick, its Puma by default. Secondly, in this scenario it does not matter whether heroku is multi-threaded or not because the app itself is running on 'localhost'.